# C++ Find/Substring Bug

Tags: c++, string

I made a c++ string, which would separate into substrings using the find and substring commands, and I keep having the issue where the substrings are more than instructed. They are supposed to be sentences with no numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string questions = "1. pog 2. pog2 3. pog3 4. pog4";
int q1in = questions.find("1.");
int q2in = questions.find("2.");
int q3in = questions.find("3.");
int q4in = questions.find("4.");
int q5in = questions.find("5.");
int q6in = questions.find("6.");
int q7in = questions.find("7.");
string q1 = questions.substr(q1in,q2in);
string q2 = questions.substr(q2in,q3in);
string q3 = questions.substr(q3in,q4in);
string q4 = questions.substr(q4in,q5in);
q1.erase (0,2);
q2.erase (0,2);
q3.erase (0,2);
q4.erase (0,2);
cout << q1 << endl;
cout << q2 << endl;
cout << q3 << endl;
cout << q4 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `substr` is a length, not an index - the string class is ancient and has a somewhat surprising interface. (I have lost count of how many times I've got this wrong.)

You want

```
string q1 = questions.substr(q1in, q2in - qin1);
```

and so on.

You can also strip off the "tag" directly,

```
string q1 = questions.substr(q1in + 2, q2in - qin1 - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're passing the index of the start of next substring, instead of passing length to `substr` method. Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string questions = "1. pog 2. pog2 3. pog3 4. pog4";
int q1in = questions.find("1.");
int q2in = questions.find("2.");
int q3in = questions.find("3.");
int q4in = questions.find("4.");
int q5in = questions.find("5.");
int q6in = questions.find("6.");
int q7in = questions.find("7.");
string q1 = questions.substr(q1in,(q2in-q1in));
string q2 = questions.substr(q2in,(q3in-q2in));
string q3 = questions.substr(q3in,(q4in-q3in));
string q4 = questions.substr(q4in,(q5in-q4in));
q1.erase (0,2);
q2.erase (0,2);
q3.erase (0,2);
q4.erase (0,2);
cout << q1 << endl;
cout << q2 << endl;
cout << q3 << endl;
cout << q4 << endl;
}
```